# Use enum values to call different methods

Tags: java, enums

Problem :  I need to perform different actions or executing different line of codes (which can be done by calling different methods) based on different Enum values and don't want to use if else.

Suppose I have following enum :

```
public enum Sports
{
  FOOTBALL, HOCKEY;
}
```

Can we use Sports.FOOTBALL and Sports.HOCKEY to call different methods with same name (method overloading) or even different methods with different name ?

```
public void method(parameter(s)) //call this method when Enum is Sports.FOOTBALL
{

}

public void method(parameter(s)) //call this method when Enum is Sports.HOCKEY
{

}
```

Both methods are part of the same class. I am looking solution for any of the case (when method have same name or different name).

Comment: This is very much an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What is the real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Sweeper I need to perform different actions based on different Enum values and don't want to use if else

Comment: Offhand I'd say that Sport(s) should be an abstract class or an interface instead of an enum, then have `public class Football extends Sport` or `public class Hockey implements Sport` then each of them can have their own implementation of `public void method(...)`

Comment: Should (1) all enums support calling same methods like both Football and Hockey should allow to call `foo()` and `bar()` methods on them but their action should depend on which enum was used to call that method OR (2) do you want to allow calling some methods only on specific enum values, like on `Football` we can call `foo()` but not `bar()` and on `Hockey` we can call `bar()` but not `foo()` method?

Comment: @Pshemo  (2) is what i want.

Comment: Then `enum` is not what you want. If you want different *interface/API* you want different *type*. Values of `enum` are of same type which is enum itself (like both `Football` and `Hockey` are of type `Sports`  and type `Sports` - like any other types - can represent only one set of methods).

Comment: One Pattern often used for that is a registry, merely a Map<Sports,SportHandler>. SportHandler is an inteface the has the methed(parameters) signature.
Then you can call `registry.get(sport).method(parameters)` once the registry is initalized.

Answer (score 5):

Method signatures need different **types** so that the compiler can distinguish them.

But: the type of your enum is `Sports`. `Sports.Football` or `Sports.Hockey` are just instances of that type; more or less like "1" and "2" are instances of the String type.

Thus: no overloading possible for different enum constants.

The "best" you can achieve would be to `switch()` over your enum instance, and then "dispatch" accordingly, or as mentioned in the comments: a Map that can `map` your different enum constants to some sort of "executable code block".